# Concurrent Writes to the same S3 file - Updates from multiple s3 buckets to target S3 bucket file using Lambda S3 Trigger

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture

My use-case is to design a system to keep reading events (**`content`**) from **Source S3 Buckets** and merge with the file present in the **Target S3 Bucket** continuously.

For instance,

Bucket-1(**`A`**) |
Bucket-2(**`B`**) |
Bucket-3(**`Target`**)

**`A`**:  Any Update ---> Trigger Lambda (**`L`**) ---> Read file from **`Target`** and merge the newly uploaded **`content`** and write back to **`Target`**

**`B`**:  Any Update ---> Trigger Lambda (**`L`**) ---> Read file from **`Target`** and merge the newly uploaded **`content`** and write back to **Target**

These events can happen at the same time and the lambda should keep on updating the same file in **`Target`**.

How can we guarantee consistency of data in **`Target`** Bucket?

I can think of the following approaches:

1. Setting lambda concurrency limit to `1`: One write operation on `Target` at a time
2. Implement locking mechanism on `Target` Bucket.
3. Schedule a `CRON job to trigger lambda at a particular time` and read all the source buckets and merge the newly uploaded content with the existing one and then write to the target s3 bucket.

> Any recommendations?